# can't submit a modal button in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with rows from a MySQL table and a delete button that confirm desired action before submit.
The modal work fine, and post all form input and submit when user confirm except the value from submit delete button, I know it's something with the modal.

I'm using bootstrap 3 and dialog confirm from here: http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

My php code is generating this html:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="myscript.php?id=1" method="post" id="myform">
<button id="del-1" name="del[1]" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    <label for="name-1"> Name</label><input type="text" name="name-1" value="Some name">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#del-1").confirm({
            title:"Delete Some name",
            text:"Are you sure?",
            confirm: function(button) {
                $('#myform').submit();
            },
            cancel: function(button) {
            },
            confirmButton: "Yes, delete!",
            cancelButton: "No"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button id="del-2" name="del[2]" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    <label for="name-2"> Name</label><input type="text" name="name-2" value="Some othername">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#del-2").confirm({
            title:"Delete Some othername",
            text:"Are you sure?",
            confirm: function(button) {
                $('#myform').submit();
            },
            cancel: function(button) {
            },
            confirmButton: "Yes, delete!",
            cancelButton: "No"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button type="submit" title="Edit names" name="edit">Edit names</button>
</form>
```

---

So when I click on "Edit names" button it is submitted to php and when I click on "Yes, delete!" button it is posted but don't post the values `"del[1]" or "del[2]"(var_dump($_POST))`, its just post all others forms values.

How can I get the post from `"del[x]"` when user click in confirmButton?

Comment: The only values I see are in the two input fields ("name-1" and "name-2"). What values do "del[1] and del[2]" refer to?

Comment: Hi, "name-1" and "name-2" are the input fields and handled by $_POST['edit'] with select and update query and "del[1]" and "del[2]" are handled by if(isset($_POST['del']) with other query (delete). The button "Yes, delete!" just submit "name-1", "name-2" and "edit" to $_POST, I need to get "del[1]" or "del[2]" when user submit using the confirmation dialog (button "Yes, delete!").

Comment: "del[1]" is the name of a button. You can't submit a button.

Comment: Hi! I can't submit a button but I can't detect when it is submited. Sorry, my english is not good enough. Check this: http://jeffersonrosa.com.br/teste.php and submit [x] button and submit the [submit] button and you will see the values will change in the $_POST array, with the confirmation dialog, I can't get when user submit the [x] button. That is my question. I just want know when a user submit a button that came from a button from dialog confirmation (yes button) and detect it with php with if(isset($_POST[del])). Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying you can't tell which button is submitting the form?

Comment: Hi! Exactly, my $_POST array can only see the main submit button, that [x] button because the js is not passed to the post, is like that javascript are trying to send the [x] pressing the other submit button and I don't want it, I need to see which button was pressed and that can be only the main submit button or one of these "del" buttons. Please compare: http://preview.tinyurl.com/lymlbwx (here I can see the x button, and there I can't see in the array: http://preview.tinyurl.com/oa2xtcv (that is the problem I want to solve).

Comment: I figured out my page without js send the "del" button and with js don't send. Any help will be very appreciated.